# declare a block of code using comments in intellij with ability to collapse

Tags: intellij-idea, comments

I have a bunch of code like this:

```
// methods related to Provider X
public void methodA() {...}
public String someOtherMethod {...}
public void increaseRankOfProviderX {...}
// end of 'methods related to Provider X'
```

I want IntelliJ to know this part as a block and I also want to collapse them, is there a way or plugin available I can achieve this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding).

Two ways you can fold the code in IntelliJ IDEA:

NetBeans-like:

```
//<editor-fold desc="...">
... code ...
//</editor-fold>
```

VisualStudio-like:

```
//region <...>
... code ...
//endregion
```

Note that line commenting symbols for "region...endregion" can be changed from "//" to "#" if the '#' character is supported by a language. But by default custom folding comments use the same comment characters as normally used for language line comments.

Instead of typing the comments manually, in many cases you can invoke a 'Surround With' action for the highlighted code with `Ctrl+Alt+T`:

[image]